# How to use the form value in the action?

Tags: html, forms, grails

I am trying to make a form in html that uses the value you enter to form the destination URL.

```
<form action="../search/${params.q}" method="post" id="q">
Busqueda: <input type="text" name="q" /><br />
</form>
```

This is what i am doing, but it does not work, any cluess?  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to handle this using a script - either server-side or on the client (JavaScript).

HTML alone can't handle parameters in the way you're using them.

So you'd need to either POST the form (as you're already doing) and handle the postback by redirecting your request to the new address, or use JavaScript to capture the field's value when a submit button is clicked and loading the new address in the browser window.

I'd suggest server-side is the best option as JavaScript might be disabled or unavailable.